# How to change the (physical) keyboard language in android?(Besides SHIFT-SPACE)

Tags: android, keyboard, usb-otg, logitech

I bought an OTG cable for my LG-G2. I connected to the OTG a wireless logitech keyboard (MK 250). In my keyboard layout I got 2 Languages: English and Hebrew.
When I press SHIFT-SPACE (language change), I see on the top of the screen the EN(English layout) changes to HE(Hebrew layout) but when I press a button, it types in English while the HE is on the top of the screen. Is there is anyway that this keyboard will type in Hebrew? I tried thitd party apps but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Does your keyboard have hebrew keys?  Because if not its unlikely to be generating hebrew letters.  Have you tried plugging in a hebrew keyboard?

Comment: I do have Hebrew letters on my keyboard

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.
I found an app called "external keyboard helper pro". with the app I found a way to change the layout. to switch languages, I just need to change the external keyboard helper to the built in LG keyboard.
Thank you Gabe for your help.

Answer (score 2):

for my case it was a tricky way to solve this issue so this method may work for some individuals
I think this issue is cause of an android bug because this method isnt too logical...

1 - go to physical keyboard settings
you can find it from your keyboard setting (Gboard,swiftkey,etc..)  its some option like : "android physical keyboard settings"
or maybe you can find it in a location like this :  settings->language and input ->  physical keyboard settings
2 - choose your physical keyboard -> Set up keyboard layouts
3 - toggle the language  layout options you need

IMPORTANT !!:
maybe you would see the layouts which you have toggled on turn off after exiting "Keyboard layouts" page
in this case :

1 - first go to physical keyboard -> Set up keyboard layouts
2 - then DONT USE TOUCH TO TOGGLE LAYOUT OPTIONS instead toggle the layout options you want with pressing space on your physical keyboard
(you can navigate through that page using arrow keys too) this way the toggle remains turned on and when you exit that page
it works and doesnt turn off like when you have toggled that layout with touch

as wierd as it is... but this solved the issue in my case maybe its because of some android bug

Comment: I had the same issue and could solve it without any extra app, thanks to your answer!